# Static file serving web2py/apache2

Tags: apache2, web2py

I have a setup with web2py (1.89) and Apache2, as in the example in the web2py book. 
Apache is supposed to be serving the static files according to this directive, but it does not:

```
AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(.*)
/users/www-data/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2
<Directory /users/www-data/web2py/applications/*/static/>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I cannot find what is wrong.

The original post had 'ˆ' instead of '^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you copied this from the PDF manual. That is not a caret that is a unicode character that looks like a caret.

Apache does not complain about, but does not see it as the start of a pattern.

Comment: Maybe you should update the question to read correctly if some paste from here. I had the same problem, in terminal program those carets and these characters really look the same.